# S3 Static Website AWS Lambda Fn Contact Form Blocked by CORS Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Purpose: Create AWS Lambda Function to enable Contact Form (HTML 5, Bootstrap 5, React or similar) to send contact information to a given email.

Conclusion: The Lambda Function works great, but I am not sure where, what, or how to adjust the CORS Policy to allow the passing of the data. I have a static website setup behind Cloudfront with an ACM-issued Certificate for HTTPS security, which I plan to move to, but I must confirm that I am using the Contact Form correctly.

Code: Contact Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2 class="mb-4">Contact Form</h2>
            <form id="contactForm">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="phoneNumber" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="emailAddress" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="comment" class="form-label">Comment</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" rows="3" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap JS and dependencies -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Collect form data
        const formData = {
            firstName: document.getElementById('firstName').value,
            lastName: document.getElementById('lastName').value,
            phoneNumber: document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value,
            emailAddress: document.getElementById('emailAddress').value,
            comment: document.getElementById('comment').value
        };

        // Send data to AWS Lambda function
        fetch('https://XXXXX5f646452XXXXXXyhzwfu40evqXc.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            alert(data.message); // You can handle the response accordingly
            // Optionally, reset the form
            document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            alert('An error occurred. Please try again later.');
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code: AWS Lambda Function

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ses = new AWS.SES();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);

        // Extracting form fields
        const firstName = requestBody.firstName;
        const lastName = requestBody.lastName;
        
        const phoneNumber = requestBody.phoneNumber;
        const emailAddress = requestBody.emailAddress;
        const comment = requestBody.comment;

        // Validate form fields if necessary

        // Sending email using SES
        await sendEmail(firstName, lastName, subject, phoneNumber, emailAddress, comment);

        // Placeholder success response
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Contact form submitted successfully!',
            }),
        };

        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Internal Server Error',
            }),
        };
    }
};

async function sendEmail(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, comment) {
    const params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ['preston3271@gmail.com'], // Replace with your email address
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: `
                        First Name: ${firstName}
                        Last Name: ${lastName}
                        
                        Phone Number: ${phoneNumber}
                        Email Address: ${emailAddress}
                        Comment: ${comment}
                    `,
                },
            },
            Subject: { Data: 'New Contact Form Submission' },
        },
        Source: 'preston3271@gmail.com', // Replace with your SES-verified email address
    };

    await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
}
```

Error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://XXXXXX.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/' from origin 'http://...highexports.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Lambda Function Test Results

> START RequestId: 329e44e6-34b2-4d0c-b32f-c441633fba13 Version: $LATEST
> END RequestId: 329e44e6-34b2-4d0c-b32f-c441633fba13
> REPORT RequestId: 329e44e6-34b2-4d0c-b32f-c441633fba13  Duration: 1009.93 ms    Billed Duration: 1010 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 82 MB

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Contact form submitted successfully!\"}"
}
```

Comment: Have you configured CORS for your Lambda function URL properly per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-configuration.html#urls-cors)? What happened when you did?